# ¿Por qué "crontab -e" no funciona dentro de un script con el usuario "root"?

Tags: linux, crontab, red-hat

En una tarea automatizada hago:

```
crontab -e
*/5 * * * * sh  /home/hardeningdb/script.sh
```

el problema es con el usuario  **root**  no  ejecuta  el comando de crontab **no hace nada** pero en otro  usuario **hardeningdb** sí lo ejecuta sin ningun problema.

¿Qué hago para que root ejecute crontab?

Comment: Y, fuera del crontab, como superusuario se puede ejecutar tu script?

Comment: si exactamente  en con root no se ejecuta y con otro usuario que no es root si

Comment: Qué errores te aparecen cuando ejecutas el script (fuera del crontab) cuando eres superusuario?

Comment: fuera del crontab  lo ejecuto manualmente  con ./script.sh y funciona sin ningun problema

Comment: Trata de poner esto `sudo journalctl -t CRON | less` o CROND, y ves busca qué es lo que está fallando, qué es lo que te dicen los logs. Puedes buscar en less con el la tecla "/" y ahí poner el nombre de tu script para ir a los registros con ese nombre. Además, trata de utilizar una ruta completa a un programa como `/bin/bash` o `/bin/sh`

Comment: gracias lo pondre a prueba y te comento que me muestra

Comment: logre solucionarlo el unico detalle tenia es que en la estructura me faltaba era agregar el nombre del usuario  gracias por el apoyo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solucion de problemas en el crontab**

1. Comprobar que todo lo que ejecutes dentro del script tenga los paths absolutos.
2. Añade en el script en la primera linea #!/bin/bash.
3. chmod 755 del fichero para que se ejecute solo, sin necesitar invocar antes sh.
4. Prueba a que el usuario root lo ejecute desde el raiz

Si no funciona el script cambia #!/bin/bash por #!/bin/bash -x y cambia en el cron para que se redirija la salida standard a un fichero tal que asi 5 * * * * /root/miscript.sh > /tmp/myscript.log

En el fichero de log verás la ejecución paso por paso y podrás ver qué falla. 
También si ves el correo de root verás donde ha fallado, cron por defecto te manda un correo con el resultado. Con el comando mail, en el prompt pon el último número que aparece y verás el mail.

Comment: gracias  por el apoyo :)